# Prime number of outcomes in event, prove the total outcomes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, logic, proof-writing, prime-numbers

So here's the problem:

x is a prime number. Let T be a number of total possible outcomes in a uniform distribution (no outcome is more likely than another). Let W and Q be independent events, each containing exactly x number of outcomes. Prove that T must either =x, or =$x^2$.
I think that the best way to approach this is with a proof by cases, but I keep getting stuck. I think that the intersection between W and Q must be $x^2$/T, but thats as far as I've gotten. I can't find a rule or anything to justify the two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- $\mathbb P(W) = \mathbb P(Q) = \frac{x}{T}$
- $W$ and $Q$ are independent $\mathbb P(W\cap Q)=\mathbb P(W) \mathbb P(Q)$
- As you say the intersection between $W$ and $Q$ must be $\frac{x^2}{T}$ outcomes
- So $\frac{x^2}{T}$ must be an integer, i.e. $T$ must divide $x^2$
- $x$ is a prime number, restricting the possibilities for $T$
- $\frac{x}{T} \le 1$

Answer (score 1):

We have $\Pr(W)=\Pr(Q)=\frac xT$.  By independence, $\Pr(W\cap Q)=\frac{x^2}{T^2}$.  Let $n=|W\cap Q|$, so that $\Pr(W\cap Q)=\frac nT$.  Then we have $\frac{x^2}{T^2}=\frac nT$ so that $x^2=nT$.

Can you finish it now?